# SmartGWT, SmartClient differences

Tags: javascript, smartgwt, web-frameworks, smartclient

Is SmartClient same with SmartGWT? If not what's the difference between the two and which is a better tool to create a web application?

Comment: I would take GWT because I simply prefer idea+maven instead of npm+babel+webpack+typescript+eslint+jest

Answer (score 1):

Many answer on the web about this:
`Smartclient` is the base Javascript framework
`Smartgwt` is a Gwt wrapper of this framework.
You choose the one whiche is more appropriate to your development skills and uses

Comment: what does GWT wrapper exactly means? how does this work? sorry about my questions I really want to explore these both frameworks. I'm a newbie. bear with me.

Comment: `GWT` is Google Web Toolkit; see [gwt.org](http://www.gwtproject.org/).  Basically `SmartGWT` is server side Java and `Smartclient` is client side Javasript. `SmartGWT`generates web documents as `Smartclient`.  If you are starting from scratch you can develop your entire solution in `SmartGWT` in Java, with `Smartclient` you can add it to web apps. I have used `Smartclient` with both `PHP` and `ASP.NET`.

Answer (score 1):

SmartGWT is based on java code and when compiled it transforms it into java script, is a heavy since it transforms java code into js.

SmartClient is a framework based on js, you can use its components in an xml page and you manipulate them in Js, and it’s light.